# template to similar fields in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsl-fo

my xml file

```
...
<element1>
    <year>1</year>
    <month>5</month>
    <days>3</days>
</element1>

<element2>
    <year>2</year>
    <month>4</month>
    <days>5</days>
</element2>
...
```

my xsl-fo template

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="//element1/years"/>
    <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="//element1/month"/>
    <xsl:text> month </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="//element1/days"/>
    <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
</fo:block>

...

<fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="//element2/years"/>
    <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="//element2/month"/>
    <xsl:text> month </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="//element2/days"/>
    <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
</fo:block>
```

As you can see, here is a similar blocks of code.
How can i simplify this expressions ? 
What kind of template should use ?

I wrote a template like this

```
<xsl:template match="element1">
    <xsl:value-of select="years"/>
    <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
    <xsl:text> month </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="days"/>
    <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

and used it

```
<fo:block>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="element1"/>
</fo:block>
```

but its not applicable to element2...

Comment: Without knowing all the details, I would say that having two elements "element1" and "element2" with the same structure smells of bad XML design, and my usual policy with badly designed XML input is to split the task into two: first do a transformation that cleans up the XML and turns it into well-designed XML, then do another transformation that does the real work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given XML (credits go to @michael.hor257k):

```
<parent>
    <element1>
        <year>1</year>
        <month>5</month>
        <days>3</days>
        <hour>12</hour>
        <minute>32</minute>
    </element1>
    <element2>
        <year>2</year>
        <month>4</month>
        <days>5</days>
        <hour>0</hour>
    </element2>
</parent>
```

**I. Match multiple elements in pattern for template**

```
<xsl:template match="element1 | element2">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
    <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
    <xsl:text> month </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="days"/>
    <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

**II. Call-Teamplate**

```
<xsl:template match="element1">
  <xsl:call-template name="renderOutput"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="renderOutput">
  <fo:block>
    <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
    <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
    <xsl:text> month </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="days"/>
    <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
  </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

[by default the context node within call-template picks up the context node of caller! Not needed but also ok, go ahead with `<xsl:with-param name="this" select="."/>` and `<xsl:value-of select="$this/year"/>`]

Answer (score 1):

Well, given:

```
<parent>
  <element1>
    <year>1</year>
    <month>5</month>
    <days>3</days>
  </element1>
  <element2>
    <year>2</year>
    <month>4</month>
    <days>5</days>
  </element2>
</parent>
```

you could do:

```
<xsl:template match="parent">
    <fo:wrapper>
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
            <fo:block>
                <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
                <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
                <xsl:text> months </xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="days"/>
                <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
            </fo:block>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </fo:wrapper>
</xsl:template>
```

to get:

```
<fo:wrapper>
  <fo:block>1 years 5 months 3 days </fo:block>
  <fo:block>2 years 4 months 5 days </fo:block>
</fo:wrapper>
```

---

> i don't need to select all elements, i just want to apply this kind of
>   template to elements with similar childs, in deferent places

In such case, you could call a *named template* - for example:

```
<xsl:template match="element1">
    <xsl:call-template name="duration"/>
</xsl:template>
...
<xsl:template match="element1">
    <xsl:call-template name="duration"/>
</xsl:template>
...    
<xsl:template name="duration">
    <fo:block>
        <xsl:value-of select="year"/>
        <xsl:text> years </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="month"/>
        <xsl:text> months </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="days"/>
        <xsl:text> days </xsl:text>
    </fo:block>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: i don't need to select all elements, i just want to apply this kind of template to elements with similar childs, in deferent places

Comment: @guesswho Please post a more representative example, then.